# How show list checked in Angular 5

Tags: angular, checkbox, frontend

I develop function for added and edit list users in my application, when i add user just i checked of this, it's work, but the problem when edit user, 
I want to show list of users that are checked, so the question is: how to display the options that are checked.
i develop the application with Angular 5
code of edit.ts:

```
processEdit(form) {
  var form = form.currentTarget.parentElement.parentElement;
  var UID = $(form).find('#UIDInput').val();
  var RoleName = $(form).find('#RoleNameInput').val();

  let checked;
  let checked_name;
  let c = Array<AUserRole>();
  $('input:checkbox[name="optapp"]').each(function (i) {
    checked_name = $(this).val();
    checked = $(this).attr('id');
    let isSelected = $(this).prop('checked');
    if (isSelected) {
      let newapp = new UserRole();
      newapp.UserName = checked_name;
      newapp.UserId = checked;
      c.push(newapp);
    }
  });
  let d: any = Array<UserRole>();
  Helpers.setLoading(true);
  let u = new Role;
  u.IsAdministrateur = this.IsAdministrateur;
  u.RoleName = RoleName;
  for (var i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {
    u.UserRoles = new UserRole();
    let k = new ApplicationRole();
    k.RoleName = RoleName;
    k.UserName = c[i].UserName;
    k.UserId = c[i].UserId;
    d.push(k);
    u.UserRoles = d[i];
  }
  u.UserRoles = d;
  u.UID = UID;
  u.RoleName = RoleName;
  this.edit(u);
  Helpers.setLoading(false);
  $('.modal').modal('hide');
```

part of .html:

```
<form #frmEdit="ngForm">
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-md-12 form-group" hidden>
                    <input class="form-control" id="UIDInput" value="">
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-12 form-group">
                    <label><b>Libelle :</b></label>
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Libelle" id="RoleNameInput" ngModel #_qn="ngModel" name="_qn">
                    <div *ngIf="_qn.invalid && (_qn.dirty)" class="text-danger">
                      <div *ngIf="_qn.errors.required">Libelle is required.</div>
                      <div *ngIf="!_qn.errors.valid && !_qn.errors.required">Invalid Libelle.</div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                  <div class="m-section">
                    <div class=" form-group">
                      <label class="menu"><b>My Users:</b></label>
                      <div class="form-group" style="margin-left:30px">
                        <div class="row">
                          <div>
                            <div class="check-list mlist" *ngFor='let user of users'>
                              <label class="ui-checkbox">
                                <input type="checkbox" value="{{user.Libelle}}" name="optapp" id="{{user.UID}}">
                                <span class="input-span"></span>
                                {{user.Libelle}}
                              </label>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>                            
                <br />
                <div>
                  <button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" (click)="processEdit($event)">submit</button>
                  <button data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-sm btn-default">cancel</button>
                </div>
              </form>
```

and this file .service.ts:

```
async editRole(role: Role) {
    let result = await this.http.put(this.pathAPI + 'role', role)
      .toPromise()
      .then(function (res) {
       // alert(res)
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        return (err)
      })
  }
```

Comment: can you share some code ?

Comment: @malbarmawi, okey

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```
 <div class="check-list mlist" *ngFor='let user of users; let i = index'>
   <label class="ui-checkbox">
     <input type="checkbox" (change)="setUser($event.target.checked, i)" [checked]="user.checked" />
```

What this will do is if the value of the input change it will trigger the (change). This change can change the value of the user.

So what you can do in the component is:

```
public setUser(_value: any, _index: number) {
  this.users[_index].checked = _value;
}
```

Comment: thank's for this answer, but there is a problem in **.checked** in the component.ts